# "Authoritative" vs. "Authorative"

Tags: spelling

I just learned that a word "Authoritative" exists. Up until now I have always used the word "Authorative", which I must have picked up along the way when I was browsing some technical documentation (I'm a software engineer).

I have looked up "Authorative" in Merriam Webster and on Wiktionary, and the word does not exist there. However, a general Google search for "Authorative" turns up quite a few references. Are all these people (including myself) really using a mis-spelled word, or is "Authorative" just a variant spelling?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings/A

Comment: It's the first time I see (or remember seeing) “authorative”. I'd say it isn't an English word at all. It doesn't even make much sense as a misspelling of *authoritative*: *authoritative* is about *authority*, not about *author*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Authorative* is a misspelling.

I looked up *"authorative"* in as many online dictionaries as I could find (well, actually, I had [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=authorative&ls=a) do it for me, but same effect), and found only one result, in [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/authorative). However, that one result does not actually contain a definition, just some examples of use. All of the examples clearly meant to say *"authoritative"*.

Google is immaterial here: people misspell things on the internet. If you mean to say that something is

> Having or arising from authority; official

then you need to write *authoritative*.

(Note that the reason for this is that this is an adjectival form of *authority*, not of *author*.)

Answer (score -2):

Authoritive: A person with the authority to command action from others.

In regard to the word, authoritative, it has no value in this context.

Comment: This seems to be rather scrambled. "Authoritive" is not a word, and is also not what the question mentions. "Authoritative" is the (only) correct spelling.